# Mapping an array in asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to map up a controller function to my web api.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "RPCRoutingApiCaseStudy",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{ServiceID}",
              defaults: new { ServiceID = RouteParameter.Optional }
              );
```

The issue is, in my controller, ServiceID is supposed to be an array. How can I set up my mapping to accept an array, and what would it look like? Sorry if that's an obvious question, but I'm very unfamiliar with this stuff and I'm trying to learn.

I understand how to do it with a regular parameter, where like for int I'd type `url/api/controller/method/5`

I just don't know what to do for an array.

Comment: Refer to this article here - [Web API Catch All Route Parameter Binding](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-catch-all-route-parameter-binding)

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass complex types into Web API you need to make that helper class that contains an IENumerable type then pass that object into the Web API via JSON encapsulation.

The following example accepts a POST method and takes a CustomListType object that contains a List. You can then do what you like with the object.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public bool POST(CustomListType myList)
    {
        //Do stuff here

        return true;
    }

    public class CustomListType
    {
        public List<int> myArray { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Using [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for Chrome; You can test the post by sending the object:

```
{myArray:[0,1,2]}
```

Note that because CustomListType has a member called "myArray" we also have "myArray" in our JSON object.

If you put a debug line in there you should be able to see the objects and the values of "myArray"

Comment: This makes no sense, the client sends the array. The controller binds it to `myList` and then you enumerate `myList` adding the data to the same type that the model binder already bound.

Comment: The controller doesn't do anything productive. I guess what I wanted to illustrate was that if you made another CustomListType you still have to instantiate the myArray member with a List<int> type.

Comment: Right, but the model binder will do that for you.